# Java Inheritance - instance variables overriding

Tags: java

Why are Instance variables of a superclass not overidden in Inheritance ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because inheritance is intended to modify behaviour. Behaviour is exposed through methods, and that's why they can be overridden.

Fields are not behaviour but state. You don't need to modify that, nor the private methods employed by the superclass. They are intended to allow the superclass to do it's job.

Answer (score 29):

You can **hide** a field, but not **override** it.

Hiding means that a field will have a different value depending from which class it's accessed. The field in the subclass will "hide" the field in the super-class, but both exists.

That's an extremely bad practice to hide field, but works:

```
public class HideField {

    public static class A
    {   
        String name = "a";

        public void doIt1() { System.out.println( name ); };
        public void doIt2() { System.out.println( name ); };   
    }

    public static class B extends A
    {
        String name = "b";

        public void doIt2() { System.out.println( name ); };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.doIt1(); // print a
        b.doIt1(); // print a
        a.doIt2(); // print a
        b.doIt2(); // print b <-- B.name hides A.name
    }
}
```

Depending on whether the method was **overriden**, the field in `A` or `B` is accessed.

**Never do that!** That's never the solution to your problem and creates very subtle bugs related to inheritance.

Comment: Oh for multiple upvotes for the imperative advice to DO NOT DO THIS. It's much like an evil overlord transforming into a snake.... It never helps.

Comment: There are subtle reasons why you might like to : especially with static class fields which you access through specifically using the super or subclass name. "Never" is never a good thing to say ;)

Comment: Using static is totally another thing, Oracle has the same suggestion with @ewernli: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

Comment: This answer is old and has upvotes but it uses terminology in an incorrect way. Fields cannot be overloaded, rather, this is called 'hiding'. Overloading refers only to methods. See for example [8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) *"If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class."*

Comment: @Radiodef Fair enough. I fixed the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- It may break the `parent class` code. For example consider following code(What would be behavior of line `obB.getInt();` in following code if, *instance variables overriding* is allowed):

  ```
  class A
  {
      int aInt;

      public int getInt()
      {
          return aInt;
      }
  }

  class B extends A
  {
      int aInt;

      public int getInt2()
      {
          return aInt;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           B obB = new B();

           //What would be behavior in following line if, 
           //instance variables overriding is allowed
           obB.getInt(); 
      }
  }
  ```
- It is not *logical* because `child class` should have/reflect *all behaviours* of `parent class`.

So, you can only *hide* the inherited methods/variables in `child class` but can't `override`.

Following is an extract from [Java doc from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) specifying *what operation you can perform/expect from `child class`*:

> You can use the inherited members as is, replace them, hide them, or supplement them with new members:
>
> - The inherited fields can be used directly, just like any other fields.
> - You can declare a field in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass, thus hiding it (not recommended).