# overriding a variable in java

Tags: java, overriding

```
public class Foo {
      public int a = 3;
    public void addFive(){
        a += 5; System.out.print("f ");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public int a = 8;
    public void addFive(){ 
        this.a += 5; 
        System.out.print("b " ); 
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Foo f = new Bar(); 
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }
 }
```

I am getting output b 3 .why it is not giving b13 as output.Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Please use proper spacing on your code.

Comment: Variables cannot be overridden in Java. Your code does not compile because in class `Foo` the variable `a` is not defined. Please correct your code.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: As written, your code doesn't compile. a does not exist in Foo.

Comment: @prerna I suppose you are studying for the Java certification :) If so, there's a mistrake in the code you post. You forgot to put `public int a=3;` in the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming class Foo is declared as below

```
class Foo 
{

    public int a = 3;

    public void addFive()
    { 
        a += 5; 
        System.out.print("f ");
    }
}
```

1. Variables have no concept of overriding. They are just masked.
2. It is printing 3 because, when you use a superclass reference to access a variable, it accesses the variable declared in superclass only. **Remember that superclass doesn't know anything about subclass.**

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `public int a = 8` in `Foo` class instead of `Bar` class it should work... printing **B 3**.

But I suppose you are talking about a question included in the Java certification exam, so you have to correct the code of the `Foo` class adding `public int a = 3`.

You cannot override a variable in Java, but declaring in as `public` (or `protected`) in the *super-class* you can use it also in all inherited classes.

In this case the right output is **B 13** because in the test class you are using a `Bar` object as a `Foo` object, so the value of `a` is **3** and not **8**.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
        public void addFive() { 
            a += 5; System.out.print("f "); 
        }
}
```

you don't have 'a' variable defined, so this example doesn't even compile.

correct code:

```
class Foo {

       public int a;

       public void addFive() { 
          a += 5; System.out.print("f "); 
       }
}
```

and see link https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464254/1025312

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you meant to declare an integer field `a` in class `Foo`.

The answer to your question has to do with concepts of 'overriding' and 'hiding', as others have pointed out. Another way to explain it is that for member variables, there is no such thing as 'dynamic dispatch'. What that means is that, if you access a member of a certain object, the system checks *at run time* which member you mean, by looking at the class hierarchy.

So, when calling the method `f.addFive`, at run time, the system will see that your object is actually a `Bar` and not a `Foo`, and so take the `addFive` function that you defined in the `Bar` class.

That does not happen for member variables: you access `f.a` in your print statement, and at *compile time* it is decided that right there you want to access the field `a` declared in class `Foo` there -- and so, that is what will happen at run time.

Now, the *reason* that there is no dynamic dispatch for member variable access is performance: it would be very expensive to go through the whole 'see what object this really is' logic every time you just want to add some value to a member variable.