# constructor and hiding a filed in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, binding, constructor, typing

I am doing this school exercise, and I couldn't figure why the following two cases would have different results.Can someone explain why in the first case `int x` of A is 100? Hasn't the `int x` in C shadowed `int x` in A? I have commented my question in the code as well. Many thanks!

```
class A {  // Case 1 
  public int x = 1;
  public String k() { return "A" + this.x; }
 }
class B extends A {
   public int x = 10;
}
class C extends B {
  public int x = 100;
  public String k() { return "C" + this.x; }
}
class TestABC {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new C();
    C c1 = new C();
 } 
}
System.out.println(a1.x +"," + c1.x);// It prints out 1, 100.
   //However I thought it'd print out 100, 100, as the int x in C shadows int x in A.
```

Another Case is

```
class A1 { //case 2
  int x=10;
  public void method() {
  System.out.print("A:" + this.x + " ");
  }
}
class B1 extends A1 {
  int x=20;
public void method() {
  System.out.print("B:" + this.x + " ");
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
   A1 s = new B1();
   s.method();// It prints out B: 20. 
   //What's the difference between this one and a1.x in the previous example? 
   //Why it prints out the subclass but in the previous code a1.x prints out the parent class?
   }
}
```

Comment: There is a discussion of this matter here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303662/dynamic-binding-works-for-methods-why-not-for-other-members-variables

and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722110/overriding-variables-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case prints out `1, 100` because it's getting the value of the **VARIABLE**
Something like:

```
Get the value of x in A and get the value of x in C
```

Overriding happens only to **METHODS** not with VARIABLES. 
That's why in your second case it invokes the method inside the `B1` instead of the `A1`

This is called **Runtime Polymorphism**.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Let me explain it further:

When we are invoking a **method**, at runtime, instead of looking at the **reference variable's type**, the JVM looks at the **object's type** and run that method.

But with **variables**, it's the other way around, instead of looking at the **object's type**, the JVM looks at the **reference variable's type**, and get that variable

Given the following example:

```
class Animal {

    String whatAmI = "An Animal";

    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi from Animal");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    String whatAmI = "A Dog";

    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi from Dog");
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
//Reference variable type               //Object type
Animal              anAnimal            = new Animal();
Dog                 aDog                = new Dog();
Animal              anotherDog          = new Dog();

anAnimal.sayHi();       //Hi from Animal
aDog.sayHi();           //Hi from Dog
anotherDog.sayHi();     //Hi from Dog
```

We get these output because the JVM invoked the `sayHi()` method on the Object's type not the Reference variable's type.

But the thing is, it doesn't work the same way with variables.
If we try something like:

```
System.out.println(anAnimal.whatAmI);       //An Animal
System.out.println(aDog.whatAmI);           //A Dog
System.out.println(anotherDog.whatAmI);     //An Animal
```

We have these output because the JVM get the `whatAmI` variable from the Reference variable's type.

A technique to remember this is to focus on the **equal (=) sign**.

- **When invoking a method**, invoke the method on the right side of the
  equal (=) sign.
- **When getting a variable**, get the variable on the left
  side of the equal (=) sign.

Comment: So in the first case, when a1 is initiated using "A a1= new C();", it contains int x= 1 , but not int x= 100 as a class C object? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Just one more question: so in the second case, s still contains int x= 10?  If so when the method() System.out.print("B:" + this.x + " "); is called, what does "this" refer to?

Comment: On the second case x refers to 20 because in your `System.out.print()` method, you use `this` and remember, `this` refers to the *currently executing* class. Which in this case is C, so we get the value of C's x.

Comment: Sure, thank you! You mean in the second case, in method System.out.print() refers to class B1, and even though there is no object that contains int x= 20, but B1 is still the executing class, so the variable int x= 20 is used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61097/discussion-between-j-lucky-and-user3735871).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. This is runtime polymorphism or overridding.

Case 1: A a = new C();
Case 2: C c = new C();

Rules of polymorphism:

```
                                          Variable            Method          Static Method
Reference of Superclass(Case 1)             Super               Sub               Super
Reference of Subclass(Case 2)                Sub                Sub                Sub
```

These are the rules of polymorphism. So if you create any member variables of these types, you will always see results in this format.

Hence the result you see.