# Using two different classloaders to load two children of the same class

Tags: java, classloader, static-members

I have two classes, `Child1` and `Child2`, children of the class `Parent`. The class `Parent`has a static member, and the two children classes have a static method `run()` using this static member. As I have to call `Child1.run()` and `Child2.run()` inside the same application, I want that each of the child class can access its own version of the static member of the parent class.

**I know that it would be easier to put the static member of the parent class into the children class, but I can't modify the source code of the classes.**

I read around that I shoud use two different classloaders, but I don't understand how. Can someone explain me how to use classloaders to achieve the result I mentioned, maybe with some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you ask is possible using two different ClassLoaders. You need to compile your classes (`Parent`, `Child1` and `Child2`), but they should not be in the same classpath location as the class you're invoking them from (call that class `Main`).

Instead, put them somewhere on your disk in a directory or put them in a jar file.

From that location, you can create multiple classloaders, and you can use the method `loadClass` to load classes with it; and you can use reflection to invoke methods, like the method `run` on it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL childAndParentClassesLocation = new URL("c:/Somewhere/On/Your/Disk");
        ClassLoader cl1 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { childAndParentClassesLocation }, Main.class.getClassLoader());
        ClassLoader cl2 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { childAndParentClassesLocation }, Main.class.getClassLoader());

        Class child1 = cl1.loadClass("packagename.Child1");
        Class child2 = cl2.loadClass("packagename.Child2");

        Method child1Run = child1.getMethod("run");
        Method child2Run = child2.getMethod("run");

        child1Run.invoke(null); // Invoke run method on Child1
        child2Run.invoke(null); // Invoke run method on Child2
    }
}
```

P.s. this is bad design for a general purpose application, but you didn't say you were making a general-purpose application. So I don't see any reason to dumb down SO by dissuading interesting questions that help explain how the JVM works.

Comment: We'll disagree on whether this is an interesting question.  I think it's too clever by half.

Comment: Why? What if he's implementing a servlet or application container? What if he has a third party library, like he says, the is using static fields (that make it impossible to create multiple instances) and he needs to instantiate it two different ways in one applications? Is that too clever for StackOverflow? Are we only allowed to ask canned questions here?

Comment: Nope.  You're even allowed to disagree w/ me.  I see too many people resorting to contortions when something simpler would easily solve the issue.  Doing the simplest thing that can possibly work should be encouraged.  You don't do future maintainers of your code favors by being obtuse.  Polymorphism should handle this easily wo/ class loader shenanigans.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt @ thank you your answer is very clear. But I still have problems, I suppose because  `Child1` and `Child2` use a static member of a third class, `Common`. Could you please explain me what should I do to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, purpose of class level member/static member is to have one copy per JVM. what you are suggesting in your question is defeating the above purpose.

If that is the case, you should achieve it with instance level members. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464222/java-inheritance-instance-variables-overriding)